# Swing events not passed to upwards to base component

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, parent-child

I have a class called `ComponentMover` that allows you to drag around any object that's registered with it. This works if you pass it bare JPanels, but it doesn't work if the JPanel has anything inside of it, and it just stays put.

This is ComponentMover:

```
public class ComponentMover extends MouseAdapter {
    private Insets dragInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private Dimension snapSize = new Dimension(1, 1);
    private Insets edgeInsets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    private boolean changeCursor = true;
    private boolean autoLayout = false;

    private Class<?> destinationClass;
    private Component destinationComponent;
    private Component destination;
    private Component source;

    private Point pressed;
    private Point location;

    private Cursor originalCursor;
    private boolean autoscrolls;
    private boolean potentialDrag;

    private boolean shouldLock = true;

    /**
     * Constructor for moving individual components. The components must be
     * regisetered using the registerComponent() method.
     */
    public ComponentMover() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructor to specify a Class of Component that will be moved when drag
     * events are generated on a registered child component. The events will be
     * passed to the first ancestor of this specified class.
     *
     * @param destinationClass
     *            the Class of the ancestor component
     * @param component
     *            the Components to be registered for forwarding drag events to
     *            the ancestor Component.
     */
    public ComponentMover(Class<?> destinationClass, JComponent... components) {
        this.destinationClass = destinationClass;
        registerComponent(components);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor to specify a parent component that will be moved when drag
     * events are generated on a registered child component.
     *
     * @param destinationComponent
     *            the component drage events should be forwareded to
     * @param components
     *            the Components to be registered for forwarding drag events to
     *            the parent component to be moved
     */
    public ComponentMover(JComponent destinationComponent,
            JComponent... components) {
        this.destinationComponent = destinationComponent;
        registerComponent(components);
    }

    public void setLock(boolean shouldLock) {
        this.shouldLock = shouldLock;
    }

    /**
     * Get the auto layout property
     *
     * @return the auto layout property
     */
    public boolean isAutoLayout() {
        return autoLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Set the auto layout property
     *
     * @param autoLayout
     *            when true layout will be invoked on the parent container
     */
    public void setAutoLayout(boolean autoLayout) {
        this.autoLayout = autoLayout;
    }

    /**
     * Get the change cursor property
     *
     * @return the change cursor property
     */
    public boolean isChangeCursor() {
        return changeCursor;
    }

    /**
     * Set the change cursor property
     *
     * @param changeCursor
     *            when true the cursor will be changed to the Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR
     *            while the mouse is pressed
     */
    public void setChangeCursor(boolean changeCursor) {
        this.changeCursor = changeCursor;
    }

    /**
     * Get the drag insets
     *
     * @return the drag insets
     */
    public Insets getDragInsets() {
        return dragInsets;
    }

    /**
     * Set the drag insets. The insets specify an area where mouseDragged events
     * should be ignored and therefore the component will not be moved. This
     * will prevent these events from being confused with a MouseMotionListener
     * that supports component resizing.
     *
     * @param dragInsets
     */
    public void setDragInsets(Insets dragInsets) {
        this.dragInsets = dragInsets;
    }

    /**
     * Get the bounds insets
     *
     * @return the bounds insets
     */
    public Insets getEdgeInsets() {
        return edgeInsets;
    }

    /**
     * Set the edge insets. The insets specify how close to each edge of the
     * parent component that the child component can be moved. Positive values
     * means the component must be contained within the parent. Negative values
     * means the component can be moved outside the parent.
     *
     * @param edgeInsets
     */
    public void setEdgeInsets(Insets edgeInsets) {
        this.edgeInsets = edgeInsets;
    }

    /**
     * Remove listeners from the specified component
     *
     * @param component
     *            the component the listeners are removed from
     */
    public void deregisterComponent(JComponent... components) {
        for (JComponent component : components)
            component.removeMouseListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Add the required listeners to the specified component
     *
     * @param component
     *            the component the listeners are added to
     */
    public void registerComponent(JComponent... components) {
        for (JComponent component : components){
            component.addMouseListener(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the snap size
     *
     * @return the snap size
     */
    public Dimension getSnapSize() {
        return snapSize;
    }

    /**
     * Set the snap size. Forces the component to be snapped to the closest grid
     * position. Snapping will occur when the mouse is dragged half way.
     */
    public void setSnapSize(Dimension snapSize) {
        if (snapSize.width < 1 || snapSize.height < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Snap sizes must be greater than 0");

        this.snapSize = snapSize;
    }

    /**
     * Setup the variables used to control the moving of the component:
     *
     * source - the source component of the mouse event destination - the
     * component that will ultimately be moved pressed - the Point where the
     * mouse was pressed in the destination component coordinates.
     */
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        source = e.getComponent();
        int width = source.getSize().width - dragInsets.left - dragInsets.right;
        int height = source.getSize().height - dragInsets.top
                - dragInsets.bottom;
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(dragInsets.left, dragInsets.top, width,
                height);

        if (r.contains(e.getPoint()))
            setupForDragging(e);
    }

    private void setupForDragging(MouseEvent e) {
        source.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        potentialDrag = true;

        // Determine the component that will ultimately be moved

        if (destinationComponent != null) {
            destination = destinationComponent;
        } else if (destinationClass == null) {
            destination = source;
        } else // forward events to destination component
        {
            destination = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(destinationClass,
                    source);
        }

        pressed = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        location = destination.getLocation();

        if (changeCursor) {
            originalCursor = source.getCursor();
            source.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        }

        // Making sure autoscrolls is false will allow for smoother dragging of
        // individual components

        if (destination instanceof JComponent) {
            JComponent jc = (JComponent) destination;
            autoscrolls = jc.getAutoscrolls();
            jc.setAutoscrolls(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Move the component to its new location. The dragged Point must be in the
     * destination coordinates.
     */
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point dragged = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        int dragX = getDragDistance(dragged.x, pressed.x, snapSize.width);
        int dragY = getDragDistance(dragged.y, pressed.y, snapSize.height);

        int locationX = location.x + dragX;
        int locationY = location.y + dragY;

        // Mouse dragged events are not generated for every pixel the mouse
        // is moved. Adjust the location to make sure we are still on a
        // snap value.

        if (shouldLock) {
            while (locationX < edgeInsets.left)
                locationX += snapSize.width;

            while (locationY < edgeInsets.top)
                locationY += snapSize.height;

            Dimension d = getBoundingSize(destination);

            while (locationX + destination.getSize().width + edgeInsets.right > d.width)
                locationX -= snapSize.width;

            while (locationY + destination.getSize().height + edgeInsets.bottom > d.height)
                locationY -= snapSize.height;
        }
        // Adjustments are finished, move the component

        destination.setLocation(locationX, locationY);
    }

    /*
     * Determine how far the mouse has moved from where dragging started (Assume
     * drag direction is down and right for positive drag distance)
     */
    private int getDragDistance(int larger, int smaller, int snapSize) {
        int halfway = snapSize / 2;
        int drag = larger - smaller;
        drag += (drag < 0) ? -halfway : halfway;
        drag = (drag / snapSize) * snapSize;

        return drag;
    }

    /*
     * Get the bounds of the parent of the dragged component.
     */
    private Dimension getBoundingSize(Component source) {
        if (source instanceof Window) {
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment
                    .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
            return new Dimension(bounds.width, bounds.height);
        } else {
            return source.getParent().getSize();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restore the original state of the Component
     */
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!potentialDrag)
            return;

        source.removeMouseMotionListener(this);
        potentialDrag = false;

        if (changeCursor)
            source.setCursor(originalCursor);

        if (destination instanceof JComponent) {
            ((JComponent) destination).setAutoscrolls(autoscrolls);
        }

        // Layout the components on the parent container

        if (autoLayout) {
            if (destination instanceof JComponent) {
                ((JComponent) destination).revalidate();
            } else {
                destination.validate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do with this code (or the other GUI's building code) to make me able to drag and drop components with children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an adaptation of a [ComponentMover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) by @camickr. The original and your version work fine with components that have children. Perhaps the problem is elsewhere. Consider posting an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem.

Here is a simple demo:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestMove extends JPanel{
    public TestMove() {
        setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("label"));
        panel.add(new JButton("button"));

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
        panel.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 50);

        add(panel);

        ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover();
        cm.registerComponent(panel);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {   
            public void run() {   
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                TestMove panel = new TestMove();
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.pack();

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```